# Nginx only responding to two virtual server definitions out of three?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a rather confusing problem that only affects one of my three `nginx` reverse proxy servers.  I have defined a `conf` file with three virtual servers like so:

```
# Django

upstream tickets {
         server 10.11.12.10;
}

server {
       listen 107.181.80.13:80;
       #listen 107.181.80.13:443 ssl;

       #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/SL.AQTS.COM_SSL.crt;
       #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/SL.AQTS.COM_SSL.key;

       server_name members.aqtsolutions.com;


       location / {
                proxy_pass  http://tickets;
                proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
}


# Wordpress (Linux)

upstream wp_server {
         server 10.11.12.9;
}

server {
       listen 107.181.80.13:80;
       server_name ubnt.aqtsolutions.com;

       #rewrite ^/wordpress/(.*)$ /$1 last;

       location / {
                proxy_pass  http://wp_server;
                proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
                #proxy_cookie_path      /wordpress/     /;
                #sub_filter             /wordpress/     /;
                #access_log             off;
       }
}


# Wordpress (Windows)

upstream wp_server_office {
         server 50.247.86.20;
}

server {
       listen 107.181.80.13:80;
       server_name aqtsolutions.com www.aqtsolutions.com;

       #rewrite ^/wordpress/(.*)$ /$1 last;

       location / {
                proxy_pass  http://wp_server_office;
                proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
                #proxy_cookie_path      /wordpress/     /;
                #sub_filter             /wordpress/     /;
                #access_log             off;
       }
}
```

But I can only access `members.aqtsolutions.com` (Django) and `www.aqtsolutions.com/aqtsolutions.com` (Wordpress (Windows)).  `ubnt.aqtsolutions.com` comes back with "Server not found".

Like I said previously, this only seems to affect one of my reverse proxies, my others (on `.org` and `.net` domains) serve more than 2 virtual servers just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Server not found" from a browser often indicates a failure to resolve the host-name into an IP address.

I notice that **ubnt.aqtsolutions.com** does not resolve, but the other two names do.

It may be that your nginx configuration is fine and you just have a missing DNS entry.

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely correct.  I forgot that the `.com` domain has a split horizon DNS because of Exchange.  The `.net` and `.org` domains do not have DNS servers associated so they forward generically to the reverse proxy servers.

Answer (score 2):

May be because you don`t have **A** DNS record for ubnt.aqtsolutions.com

```
nslookup ubnt.aqtsolutions.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find ubnt.aqtsolutions.com: NXDOMAIN
```